# How do I conditionally remove duplicates from my dataframe based on values in one column being the same for two different values in a second column?

Tags: r, duplicates, conditional-statements, multiple-columns, multiple-conditions

I would like to remove the rows where *lognum==0* only if *date* is the **same** for *lognum==0* and *lognum==1*. However, I would like to keep all other entries for both *lognum==0* and *lognum==1* (in my dataset, every date has multiple entries). Basically, I want to preferentially keep rows in which *lognum==1* in the case that the date overlaps with *lognum==0*.

Here's a snippet of my dataframe:

```
  date         logger    lognum
  4/1/2019     RKLV      1
  4/1/2019     RKLV      1
  4/1/2019     RKLV      1
  4/1/2019     RKLV      1
  4/1/2019     RKLV      1
  4/1/2019     MPT2      0
  4/2/2019     MPT2      0
  4/2/2019     MPT2      0
  4/2/2019     MPT2      0
  4/2/2019     MPT2      0
  4/2/2019     MPT2      0
  4/2/2019     MPT2      0
11/16/2015     RTUS      0
11/16/2015     RTUS      0
11/16/2015     RTUS      0
11/16/2015     RTUS      0
11/16/2015     RTUS      0
11/16/2015     RTUS      0
11/16/2015     RTUS      0
```

Here's my desired output after removing duplicates based on the above conditions:

```
    date         logger    lognum
    4/1/2019     RKLV      1
    4/1/2019     RKLV      1
    4/1/2019     RKLV      1
    4/1/2019     RKLV      1
    4/1/2019     RKLV      1
  11/16/2015     RTUS      0
  11/16/2015     RTUS      0
  11/16/2015     RTUS      0
  11/16/2015     RTUS      0
  11/16/2015     RTUS      0
  11/16/2015     RTUS      0
  11/16/2015     RTUS      0
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make your example data copy-and-paste-able.

Comment: Your conditions did not match your output. Rows with `logger == 'MPT2' & lognum == 0` are removed even if their dates do not match with rows having `lognum == 1`